# How to get free/total space in usb otg?

Tags: android, usb

I can detect if usb otg was attached and detached in my phone but now my problem is I don't know how to retrieve all information/file in usb otg?

Comment: go to  frameworks/opt/setupwizard/ and restore original state with
'git reset --hard'

Comment: @greenapps can u help me bro?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just get the URI like `/storage/usbotg`, then do:

```
File usbotgfile = new File("/storage/usbotg");
usbotgfile.getTotalSpace();
usbotgfile.getFreeSpace();
```

It's better when you don't hardcode the URI path but use:

```
Environment.getExternalDirectory();--> /storage/sdcard0
```

Then change `sdcard0` to `usbotg`.